# Find most relevant Vector from set of vectors

Tags: python, algorithm, vector, graph, tree

I have a set of vectors of shape (1000,) (Its vector representation of images), I need to find out which of them is most closely related to others(most relevant image to represent that entity). I am going through many algorithms like kNN but I don't have any trained data to compare these vectors with, I only have these vectors. Can anyone tell me which algorithm/s I need to use to achieve this??

Answer (score 1):

**This depends completely on the kind of embedding / how those representations are computed and there is no working algorithm without using this assumption!**

You need some kind of metric, which is able to rate the similarity of two vectors!

When you do have this metric, the naive approach is a loop comparing all:

```
# linear-search
max_similarity = -inf
max_vector
for vector in all_vectors:
    similarity = similarity(my_vector, vector)
    if similarity > max_similarity:
        max_similarity = similarity
        max_vector = vector
```

For some metrics, the above can be speed up by metric-trees and similar approaches (basically the internals of kNN algorithms) which try to prune some candidates away (not looking at all candidates) using assumptions of the underlying metric (resulting in a potential speedup). These algorithms get slow in very high-dimensions, but i'm not sure if 1000 is already too much!

An example if your assumption / similarity would be based on the *euclidean metric* (using sklearn's [KDTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.KDTree)):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
X = np.vstack(my_vectors)
tree = KDTree(X)
dist, ind = tree.query(my_vector, k=1)  # get nearest neighbor
```

One example where this would be a good approach is [OpenFace](http://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/) which is completely build on the idea to map faces to euclidean-space (similar faces have low euclidean-distance)! (the underlying paper: [FaceNet](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/app/1A_089.pdf))

There is also the [BallTree](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html#sklearn.neighbors.BallTree) supporting more metrics!

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree, BallTree

KDTree.valid_metrics
    ['cityblock', 'p', 'l2', 'chebyshev', 'l1', 'euclidean', 'minkowski', 
    'infinity', 'manhattan']

BallTree.valid_metrics
    ['braycurtis', 'cityblock', 'p', 'hamming', 'dice', 'l2', 'rogerstanimoto',
     'wminkowski', 'chebyshev', 'russellrao', 'sokalmichener', 'matching', 'l1',
     'haversine', 'pyfunc', 'kulsinski', 'seuclidean', 'mahalanobis', 'euclidean',
     'minkowski', 'sokalsneath', 'infinity', 'manhattan', 'jaccard', 'canberra']
```

Again: the first sentence is the most important one here!

Comment: I think the question is slightly different: Here one vector is compared to a set of vectors, but OP asks to find the most central one without picking one first.